UIScrollView aligns its content's origin to its bound's center on first render, why is that?
I'm trying to learn UIKit and toying around with a UIScrollView. My goal is to create a UIScrollView that contains an image that I can pan and zoom.
Upon first render, as title says, the image's origin matches the UIScrollView's (bounds) center. As soon as I double tap to reset zoom, the issue fixes itself.
Issue visualization in simulator
This is my attempt:
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import SMScrollView

open class PinchableImageVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    private let dataSource: String
    
    private let minimumZoomScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    private let maximumZoomScale: CGFloat = 20.0
        
    lazy internal var scrollView: SMScrollView = { [unowned self] in
        let scrollView = SMScrollView(frame: .zero)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = self.maximumZoomScale
        
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.fast
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemMint
        
        scrollView.stickToBounds = true
        scrollView.fitOnSizeChange = false

        return scrollView
    }()
    
    lazy internal var imageView: UIImageView = {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: dataSource) else {
            fatalError("assets.xcassets doesn't include any image named \'\(dataSource)\'.")
        }
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        return imageView
    }()
    
    internal init(dataSource: String) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
     public required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Uh uh you're not expected to invoke \(#function)")
    }


    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(self.imageView)
        
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.top.right.bottom.equalTo(self.view)
        }
         
    }
    
    open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        imageView.frame = scrollView.bounds
    }
    
    public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imageView
    }
}


It's a little odd that you state you are "trying to learn UIKit" -- by using someone else's class (a POD that hasn't been updated in 9 years)? As a side note, in order for someone to help with your question, we have to install SnapKit and SMScrollView ... try working on your code without the need for 3rd-party add-ons.

@DonMag: I'm trying to learn the layouting part of UIKit, not coding reactions to events, at least yet. SMScrollView is a subclass of UIScrollView so just replace it with that and remove the two lines before return scrollView. SnapKit is an industry standard.

SnapKit may be an "industry standard," but I see many, many questions here from people using it who have trouble because they don't understand the basics of auto-layout / constraints. Setting that aside for the moment, searching for swift uiscrollview zoom pan returns many, many results with articles, tutorials, examples, etc. Probably a much better place to start than using a 3rd-party scroll view class (unless you dig into that class and understand what it's doing)..

@DonMag: The only additional behavior that SMScrollView provides in this context is to reset zoom on double tap and keep the image centered upon interface rotation. The issue persists if I replace SMScrollView with UIScrollView so it's not the source of the issue. Addressing the second part, I feel that understanding what I did wrong will help me way more than copy-pasting some online tutorial.

Assuming this is the code you are using: SMScrollView ...
After taking a quick look, adding this to your controller should center the image on launch:
open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
}

You will probably quickly find out that SMScrollView isn't handling scroll view size changes (such as on device rotation)... and, if you want to keep the image aspect ratio and set imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit, you can pan the image completely out of view.

Thank you, that was helpful. Any resource you suggest to learn how to handle UIScrollView size changes?

@NiccolòDellaRocca - you could try looking at the other properties that SMScrollView has -- maybe a combination of those will handle it. However, it's not entirely clear what your goal is... You are setting your image view frame to the same size as the scroll view -- does that mean you want non-aspect-ratio scaling? Are you determined to use SMScrollView? If not, I'll go back to my earlier suggestion: search for swift uiscrollview zoom pan and learn about how scroll views work.
